# make a counter in c++ which calculate the number of steps

Tags: c++

I make a program which require from the user to enter a number then make this number reach 1 by doing a loop if the number reach an odd value the program will multiply it by 3 then add 1 to it
if the number reach an even value the program will divide it by 2 ... until reachig 1 .so i make a counter to count the number of steps but it output wrong value .  this is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  unsigned int x;
  int counter ;
  cout<<"enter a number:"<<endl;
  cin>>x;
  while (x!=1) {
    if (x%2!=0) {
      counter++;
      x=3*x+1;
      cout<<x<<endl;
    }
    else if (x%2==0) {
      counter++;
      x=x/2;
      cout<<x<<endl;
    }
    else {
      counter++;
      cout<<x<<endl;
    }
  }
  cout<<"the value of the counter is :"<<counter;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize the counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t init `counter` variable so it can contain any number. Set it to zero when declare:

```
int counter = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not initialize `counter`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned int x;
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "enter a number:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    while (x != 1) {
        if (x % 2 != 0)
            x = 3 * x + 1;
        else if (x % 2 == 0)
            x = x / 2;
        counter++;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    cout << "the value of the counter is :" << counter;
}
```